# TrueCrypt drive letter remains after dismount

Tags: truecrypt

I have a system on a Windows 2008 Server, inside a TrueCrypt volume. The volume is in the Administrator user folder, owned by the Administrator. Dismounting the volume from the Administrator account works every time, but about once in four cases the drive letter remains there.

The letter is always visible (but cannot be accessed) in Total Commander, sometimes in Windows Explorer and never in Disk Manager. Mountvol also does not find it. The only way I was able to get rid of it was rebooting.

Command I use to dismount (from a batch file ran by Task Scheduler):

```
"c:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe" /f /dz /w /q /s
```